# How can I select the dang value of this div from within my script?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, traversal

// This line works:

```
var remove = jQuery(this).closest('.item').hide();
```

// Why doesn't this line work in the same script a few lines down?

```
var discount_amount = jQuery(this).closest('.discount_amount').text();
```

I am just trying to get the value of the closest div with a class of .discount_amount and assign it to the variable :-/ Am I missing something here?

File is here:
http://www.extremecouponnetwork.com/templates/ja_wall/js/clip.js

HTML HERE:

```
<a class="clip_it" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="jfbc.opengraph.triggerAction('1','http://www.extremecouponnetwork.com<?php echo $this->item->link; ?>')  "><img src="/templates/ja_wall/images/scissors_add.png" /><span>Clip It</span></a>
    <img src="/templates/ja_wall/images/animated_scissors.gif" class="ToBeAnimated">

    <br />
    <div class="discount_amount" style="display:  !important;"><?php echo $this->item->extraFields->DiscountAmount->value; ?></div>
    <div class="percent_off" style="display:  !important;"><?php echo $this->item->extraFields->PercentOff->value; ?></div>
    <div class="brand_avg_sale" style="display:  !important;"><?php echo $this->item->extraFields->BrandAvgSale->value; ?></div>
```

Comment: You know what would help? HTML.

Comment: Yes, you're missing the HTML.

Comment: have you tried `.val()` instead of `.text()`? We don't really need to see the rest of your javascript, but some of the HTML would help.

Comment: Is `.discount_amount` a parent of `this`?

Comment: Why would `val()` (for `input` and `textarea` elements) work?

Comment: Indeed, the actual HTML would be very useful. Also, the `closest()` method might not do what you think it does. It returns the closest __ancestor__ that matches the specified selector. This might not match your expectation of 'closest', as it absolutely does not look at siblings.

Comment: Sorry... I added a link to the site... to see the html you have to authenticate with FB though :-/   I tried .val btw

Comment: Grampa... Thanks... yeah... I am trying to select the closest sibling div (at the same level as the link)

Comment: "to see the html you have to authenticate with FB though" *No*. Put the relevant HTML *here* in your question. That way, once *you've* fixed *your* code the question doesn't immediately become nonsensical to future users/visitors.

Comment: @DavidThomas, And because it's rude as hell...

Comment: geeeze... ok... I added the html... :-/

Comment: @Digital: I'm not trying to be rude with my comments, but what is `$(this)` in context? Where does the DOM traversal *start* from?

Comment: That's why I didn't just include it originally... I was trying to keep it simple in case I made an "easy fix mistake". I am in a MVC php view... and I include a file clip.js (link above)... That file ties an animation I have to a button in the html... At the bottom of the animation you can see where im trying to get the value of .discount_amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption that the elements are, as you said in your comments, siblings, then I'd suggest:

```
var discount_amount = jQuery(this).siblings('.discount_amount').text();
```

This doesn't consider proximity, it'll just take the text of the *first* element that matches the selector string passed to the `siblings()` method.

Comment: That did it... Perhaps you can un minus me now? :P

Comment: I never down-voted you, I also never voted to close. While your question needed the HTML I only wanted to prompt you to improve your question. If you hadn't improved it within an hour or so I would have voted to close, rather than down-vote in any case.